# Save card details while doing stripe payment

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hi i have been using stripe for the first time in my project where i ask user to provide their Credit card details for payment & i generate stripe token and charge the customer. I have provided a checkbox where customer can save the card details for future transactions & the requirement by the client is that if checkbox is checked, the details have to be saved once the payment successfully done. I am only getting the stripeToken in the processing via POST method and not the card details. Is it possible to get the card details back from the stripeToken in programming way or what can be an equivalent & convenient option to do it?

I tried adding the name attribute to the fields required by stripe for the token generation but in the form POST it is coming empty.

Comment: Have you tried this: [https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later)

Comment: @Maktwick: I would advise you to read carefully the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs) and [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api) provided by Stripe that are very well done.

Answer (score 0):

[Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api) Only provides the Last 4 Digits of the card . 
You can save the CustomerId provided by the Stripe API that can be used later for payments,

Comment: Saving credit card details is not allowed, that's why stripe only return the last 4 digits of the card.

Comment: Yes, don't save the credit card details locally. In most countries that's actually straight up not allowed , and you can find yourself very much sued for it, *especially* if those details get stolen. PCI compliance is something every dev that handles other peoples money should read up on. Its also almost certainly against the TOS for Stripe, paypal, banks, etc. The good news is, you CAN store the token, and this is quite safe as that token can only be used to transfer funds to yourself and thus worthless to hackers and corporate espionage

Answer (score 0):

When the checkbox is checked you can use the token to create a new customer (or update if it already exist ).
Into the [link](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later) of @vher2 you can find an example to follow.

**EDIT**:

Inside the token generated from [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form) do you have all the information you need. See the [Example Response](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token) into Api Stripe of token creation.